# Need help removing special characters rewrite htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Struggling with a 301 redirect in htaccess after changing my links on my blog.

I have the following code in htaccess today:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
Rewriterule ^blog/(.+)/(.+).html$       ./blog/view/blog.php?page=$1&mode=$2 [NC]
Rewriterule ^blog/(.+).html$            ./blog/blog.php?page=$1 [NC]
Rewriterule ^blog/(.+)/$                ./blog/view/blog.php?page=$1 [NC]
Rewriterule ^blog/$                     ./blog/blog.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
Rewriterule ^blog/(.+)/(.+)$        ./blog/view/blog.php?page=$1&mode=$2 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ ./blog/blog.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

The problem is that I´ve now in php converted special characters like 'åäö' to 'aao' but the old links to my old posts has no redirect to the new links.

Can someone please help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a simple [301 Redirect](http://jaminquimby.com/servers/125-apache-http-server/525-how-to-301-permanent-redirect-in-htaccess) that I based the following code from.

Here is an example of redirection based on extension to fit your requirement.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .html$
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*).html$ /blog/blog.php?page=$1[R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for this. I have tested it out but is does not seem to work as I want to.